# Week on Week, Day on Day and YoY Calculations on Pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, cumulative-sum

I have the following dataframe which is at a day level:

```
    BillDate    S2Rate
4   2019-06-04  4686.5
3   2019-06-03  1557.5
2   2019-05-21  10073.5
1   2019-05-19  6501.5
0   2019-05-18  1378.0
```

I want to calculate WoW percentage, WoW increase or decrease using this data. How do I do this?

Also how do I replicate this for a YoY and Day on Day?

Comment: Please see the answer added. Happy to assist further if needed

Answer (score 1):

You should use [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). Then you can use functions like [pct_change](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) and [diff](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) to get the differences:

```
# df["BillDate"] = pd.to_datetime(df["BillDate"])

week_over_week = df.set_index("BillDate").resample("W").sum()
week_over_week_pct = week_over_week.pct_change()
week_over_week_increase = week_over_week.diff()
```

You can replace the parameter for `resample` with `"D"` for day over day, `"Y"` for year over year and many other options for more complex time ranges.

Answer (score 1):

Set BillDate as index after coercing it to a datetime

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['BillDate']), inplace=True)
df
```

Get rid of BillDate from columns now that you moved it to index

```
df.drop(columns=['BillDate'], inplace=True)
```

[Resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) to required period, calculate sum and [percentage change](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html)

```
df.resample('W')['S2Rate'].sum().pct_change().to_frame()
```

Please note resample works by taking the last value in the period.

`'W'`-Sets date to Sunday

`'M'`-Sets date to last date in a month